# i can't add custom css to my rails / bootstrap project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I cant seem to figure out what i am doing wrong. I have added custom files. I have tried to override the current ones.

application.css.scss

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';

/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the    files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

i should be able to just add another style sheet correct?

Comment: your custom stylesheet file is not loaded on browser ? or your element css property is not overridden. Please elaborate.

Comment: I added a custom.css.scss to the assets/stylesheets folder. none of any css that I put in there changes the page. nothing gets over ridden. Its like the asset pipeline does not see the files.

Comment: can you inspect page and see if custom.css.scss is loaded or not.

Comment: Yea. Looks like it isnt even loading the file.

Comment: [The github](https://github.com/rjrobinson/Hot_Jobs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i had to do was add

```
@import '<insert file name here>'
```

It then worked.